# Edit user's first and last name

Tags: templating, form, user-profile

I have added a form to my front-end to edit the user's first and last name. Editing all the other fields is not a problem but when I try to edit the first or last name it doesn't work.

I think I might need to change `name="fields[firstName]"` to something else, but I don't know to what I should change it to.

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <h1 class="login-text">{{'Profiel bewerken'|upper}}</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="profile">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">  

    <label for="voornaam">{{"voornaam"|title}}</label>
    <input type="text" id="voornaam" name="fields[firstName]"
    {% if currentUser.firstName %}value="{{ currentUser.firstName }}"{% endif %}>

    <label for="achternaam">{{"achternaam"|title}}</label>
    <input type="text" id="achternaam" name="fields[lastName]"
    {% if currentUser.lastName %}value="{{ currentUser.lastName }}"{% endif %}>

    <label for="woonplaats">{{"woonplaats"|title}}</label>
    <input type="text" id="woonplaats" name="fields[woonplaats]"
    {% if currentUser.woonplaats %}value="{{ currentUser.woonplaats }}"{% endif %}>

    <label for="postcode">{{"postcode"|title}}</label>
    <input type="text" id="postcode" name="fields[postcode]"
    {% if currentUser.postcode %}value="{{ currentUser.postcode }}"{% endif %}>

    <label for="adres">{{"adres"|title}}</label>
    <input type="text" id="adres" name="fields[adres]"
    {% if currentUser.adres %}value="{{ currentUser.adres }}"{% endif %}>

    {# Check to see if the user has a photo  #}
    <label>Profielfoto</label><br />
    {% if currentUser.photoUrl %}
        <img src="{{ currentUser.photoUrl }}" alt="{{ currentUser.title }}"><br />
        <input type="file" name="userPhoto" value="Change Photo">
    {% else %}
        {# If no photo exists, give the option to upload a new one #}
        <input type="file" name="userPhoto" value="Upload">
    {% endif %}

    {# <input type="file" name="userPhoto" value="{{ (currentUser.photoUrl ? 'Change Photo' : 'Upload') }}"> #}

    <br /><button type="submit">Opslaan</button>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A User's first and last name fields don't need the `fields[]` prefix as they aren't custom fields added to the user field group.

So using the following should work:

```
<label for="voornaam">{{"voornaam"|title}}</label>
<input type="text" id="voornaam" name="firstName"
{% if currentUser.firstName %}value="{{ currentUser.firstName }}"{% endif %}>

<label for="achternaam">{{"achternaam"|title}}</label>
<input type="text" id="achternaam" name="lastName"
{% if currentUser.lastName %}value="{{ currentUser.lastName }}"{% endif %}>
```